# How to connect Events and their Handlers (from Form sub-components) with Designer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have subclassed ToolStrip thus:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PGNapoleonics.MapForm {
    public partial class DetailMapFormToolStrip : ToolStrip, IDisplayMenuOptions, ISupportInitialize {
        public DetailMapFormToolStrip() => InitializeComponent();
        public DetailMapFormToolStrip(IContainer container) { container.Add(this); InitializeComponent(); }

        public void BeginInit() { }
        public void EndInit() {
            MainMenuStrip.Visible = DesignMode;
            if (DesignMode) return;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs>     HighlightFovChange;
        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs>     HighlightHexChange;
        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs>     HighlightUnitChange;
        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public event EventHandler<ZoomEventArgs> ZoomChange;
```

and placed an instance on my form as `mapFormtoolStrip`.

Then I created a *state component* with eventhandlers thus:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PGNapoleonics.MapForm {

    public partial class GameDisplayState : Component, IGameDisplayState, ISupportInitialize {
        public GameDisplayState() => InitializeComponent();    
        public GameDisplayState(IContainer container) { container.Add(this); InitializeComponent(); }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public virtual void BeginInit() { }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public virtual void EndInit() { }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        [Browsable(true)]
        public void HighlightFovChange(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        [Browsable(true)]
        public void HighlightHexChange(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        [Browsable(true)]
        public void HighlightUnitChange(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        [Browsable(true)]
        public void ZoomChange(object sender, ZoomEventArgs e) { }
```

instantiated on the form as `gameDisplayState`.

The whole compiles and displays fine in the designer as shown here:

[image]

However the Designer won't let me connect the eventhandlers from `gameDisplayState` to the events from  `mapFormToolStrip`. The events from `mapFormtoolStrip` are visible in the designer, but `gameDisplayState` and its eventhandlers are not. When i attempt to manually type the appropriate reference (as for example `gameDisplayState.HighlightFovChange`) I get the message dialog:

[image]

[image]

Have I missed a step?

Or is this simply not possible?

The clean structure of keeping the plumbing connections in the Designer, away from the procedural code behind, quite appealed to me.

Comment: Simply not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In light of the comment above by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant):

> Simply not possible.

the workaround seems to be:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        MenuStrip.Visible = DesignMode;
        if (DesignMode) return;

        ConnectEventRelays();
    }

    #region EventRelays
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>     HighlightFovChange;
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>     HighlightHexChange;
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>     HighlightUnitChange;
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public event EventHandler<ZoomEventArgs> ZoomChange;

    [Browsable(true)]
    public void HighlightFovChangeRelay(object sender, EventArgs e) => HighlightFovChange?.Invoke(sender, e);

    [Browsable(true)]
    public void HighlightHexChangeRelay(object sender, EventArgs e) => HighlightHexChange?.Invoke(sender, e);

    [Browsable(true)]
    public void HighlightUnitChangeRelay(object sender, EventArgs e) => HighlightUnitChange?.Invoke(sender, e);

    [Browsable(true)]
    public void ZoomChangeRelay(object sender, ZoomEventArgs e) => ZoomChange?.Invoke(sender, e);

    protected virtual void ConnectEventRelays() {
        HighlightFovChange  += gameDisplayState.HighlightFovChange;
        HighlightHexChange  += gameDisplayState.HighlightHexChange;
        HighlightUnitChange += gameDisplayState.HighlightUnitChange;
        ZoomChange          += gameDisplayState.ZoomChange;
    }
    #endregion Event Relays
```

with the Designer capable only of connecting the events from `mapFormToolStrip` to handlers from `MapForm itself thus:

[image]

In light of the work required for `ConnectEventRelays()` this almost seems more worthwhile in code behind instead of the Designer.

Only available in WPF you say. Pity.